# Pandas Google Datareader only returning 1 year of stock data

Tags: python, pandas, stock

It used to be able to pull like 15 years of data, not it only returns 1 year of data regardless of your "start" date. Anyone else Having this problem?

Comment: Maybe is a problem with the "Google" side?

Comment: Could be. I used to use yahoo and they disabled their API all together

Comment: Yes, I tried some time ago and I couldn't neither. You could use [investing](https://www.investing.com/currencies/eur-usd-historical-data) but the smaller time frame is 1D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using spyder as IDE. I did following and it is working for me now:

1. right click on DataReader in "wb.DataReader(symbol, 'google', start, end)" and select "Go to definition"
2. on top of the opened page right click on GoogleDailyReader from "pandas_datareader.google.daily import GoogleDailyReader" and select "Go to definition"
3. in the opened file change 'http://www.google.com/finance/historical' to return 'http://**finance**.google.com/finance/historical'
4. close spyder and open it again. it should work!

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I will give it a try

Comment: It worked thanks!! How did you figure something like that out?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to create a wrapper for the GoogleDailyReader and change the URL in this wrapper:

```
from pandas_datareader.google.daily import GoogleDailyReader

class FixedGoogleDailyReader(GoogleDailyReader):
    @property
    def url(self):
        return 'http://finance.google.com/finance/historical'

start = datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime.now()
reader = FixedGoogleDailyReader(symbols=['AMZN', 'IBM'], start=start, end=end, chunksize=25, retry_count=3, pause=0.001, session=None)
reader.read()
```